# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': A feature with ID xx already exists

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

I am getting this familiar error while trying to deploy my solution through visula studio. Earlier I used powershell scripts but this time I am little skeptical. Here is the scenario:

I am Working on a development server, which is shared by a couple of team members.

I have taken the latest code from TFS, went offline, ie I am not connected to TFS

I made a new site through central admin and i deployed my solution to it using Visual studio. This is where i Get my error.

When i checked in Central admin, I do see the already exixting solution.

What I want to know is, if I deploy it using power shell or force attribute, will it affect the other people's exixting sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a solution can not be scoped to anything more granular than a Web Application, the feature definition will be updated for all web applications that uses the particular feature.

But the other users will have to re-enable the feature to get the new modules etc. from the feature. Another issue is with feature receivers where your feature will update the code behind in the .dll placed in GAC for all users.

Comment: So what approcah should I follow, if I want to add and test some additonal functionality, Like in my case , I want to add expand all and Collapse all Button for the tree view nodes in the website. but I dont want to imapact other team members sites.

Comment: I think the idea of a Shared development server is not the best from the beginning. One approach would be to set up one dev server for each team member, to separate your code. You could possibly use the same SQL Server and use the same service applications though (but it is a trickier setup).

Comment: yes, I know!! But this is what we are provided to wok upon in my new project, so cannot do any reconfiguration.

Comment: Then it is tricky! Since you share the code base and the features it is hard to separate. One, not so good but working, approach would be to create new features where you test out functionality and when satisfied, you move that code to one of the other features that the other team members also uses

Comment: Can you help me with the suggestion you proveided? any Link to the steps explaning?. i have added a new webpart implementing the functionality but I am clueless as to how to create feature for that?

Comment: IN your project, right click the Features folder and click "Add Feature", then you make sure to add the webpart to the feature (double click the feature and add the webpart). Here you can also set the name and scope for the webpart (use site for webparts)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9712/discussion-between-deepika-tyagi-and-robert-lindgren)